# Ajax returned an undefined php index error while the other one don't

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with ajax, when I call it, i get the undefined index error on my variables.
I have other ajax call on all my website, and no problem, but this one give me an error.
I search in my code and I don't see where my mistake is :(.

Here is my HTML :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#btnDispo').click(function()
  {
    var service = document.getElementById("serviceTest").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("DateReservation").value;
    var heure = document.getElementById("heureTest").value;
    if( service && date && heure)
    {
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "check-table.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: 
        {
          service: service, date: date, heure: heure
        },
        success: function(output_string)
        {
          $("#result_table").html(output_string);
        } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call 
    }
    else
    {
        alert("c'est pas rempli");
    }
  });
</script>
```

and this is my check-table.php :

```js
<?php
    //DB Connection
    include("connection.php"); 

    $service = isset($_REQUEST['service']) ? $_REQUEST['service'] : 'serviceBug' ;
    $date = isset($_REQUEST['date']) ? $_REQUEST['date'] : 'dateBug' ;
    $heure = isset($_REQUEST['heure']) ? $_REQUEST['heure'] : 'heureBug' ;
    $output_string = "Service = " . $service . " et date = " . $date . " et heure = " . $heure; 
/*
    $tableDispo = "SELECT numTable FROM tbltable WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblreservation WHERE tblreservation";
    $tableDispo .=".idTable = tbltable.idTblTable and tblreservation.serviceReservation = '".$service."' and tblreservation.dateReservation = '".$date."' )";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $tableDispo);

    $output_string = "";
    $output_string .=  "<table border='1'>\n";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        foreach($row as $value)
        {
            $id = $row['numTable'];
            $output_string .= "<img width='";
            $output_string .= "90%' src='";
            $output_string .= "../Images/Table";
            $output_string .= $id;
            $output_string .= ".png'>\n";
        }
        $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
    }
    $output_string .= "</table>\n";

    //mysql_close();
    // This echo for jquery */
    echo json_encode($output_string);
?>
```

I have the same in an another page, who works perfectly :
html :

```js
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  $('#btnFiltre').click(function()
  {
    var service = document.getElementById("serviceTest").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("DateReservation").value;
    var heure = document.getElementById("heureTest").value;
    $.ajax({
      url: "check-gestionTable.php",
      type:'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: 
      {
        service: service, date: date, heure: heure
      },
      success: function(output_string)
      {
        $("#result_table").html(output_string);
      } // End of success function of ajax form
    }); // End of ajax call 
  });
</script>
```

check-gestionTable.php :

```js
<?php
   //DB Connection
   include("connection.php"); 

   $service = $_POST['service'];
   $date = $_POST['date'];
   $heure = $_POST['heure'];


   if($date)//Si la date n'est pas null
   {
        if ($service != "Tout")//Si le service n'est pas null
        {
            if($heure != "Toutes")// Si heure n'est pas null
            {
                $tableDispo = "SELECT idTblReservation as Numero_de_reservation, nombreClient as Couvert, dateReservation as Date_, serviceReservation as Service, heure as Heure, idTable as Numero_de_table FROM tblreservation where serviceReservation = '".$service."' AND dateReservation = '".$date."' AND heure = '".$heure."' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $tableDispo);
                $header = false;
                $output_string = "";
                $output_string .=  "<table class='titreRes' id='titreRes' style='border: 10px ridge grey; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 35%; width: 50%; background-color: lightgrey; font-family: Cooper;'>\n";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    if(!$header)
                    {
                        $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                        foreach($row as $header => $value)
                        {
                            $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$header}</th>\n";
                        }
                        $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>Supprimer ? </th>";
                        $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
                    }
                    $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                    foreach($row as $value)
                    {
                        $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$value}</th>\n";
                    }
                    $id = $row['Numero_de_reservation'];
                    $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'><a href='delete.php?id=";
                    $output_string .= $id;
                    $output_string .= "'>Supprimer</a></th>";
                    $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
                }
                $output_string .= "</table>\n";

                // This echo for jquery 
                echo json_encode($output_string);
            }
            else if ($heure == "Toutes")
            {
                $serviceDateTable = "SELECT idTblReservation as Numero_de_reservation, nombreClient as Couvert, dateReservation as Date_, serviceReservation as Service, heure as Heure, idTable as Numero_de_table FROM tblreservation where serviceReservation = '".$service."' AND dateReservation = '".$date."' ORDER BY heure ASC";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $serviceDateTable);
                $header = false;
                $output_string = "";
                $output_string .=  "<table class='titreRes' id='titreRes' style='border: 10px ridge grey; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 35%; width: 50%; background-color: lightgrey; font-family: Cooper;'>\n";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    if(!$header)
                    {
                        $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                        foreach($row as $header => $value)
                        {
                            $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$header}</th>\n";
                        }
                        $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>Supprimer ? </th>";
                        $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
                    }
                    $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                    foreach($row as $value)
                    {
                        $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$value}</th>\n";
                    }
                    $id = $row['Numero_de_reservation'];
                    $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'><a href='delete.php?id=";
                    $output_string .= $id;
                    $output_string .= "'>Supprimer</a></th>";
                    $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
                }
                $output_string .= "</table>\n";

                // This echo for jquery 
                echo json_encode($output_string);
            }
        }
        else if ($service == "Tout")
        {
            $dateTable = "SELECT idTblReservation as Numero_de_reservation, nombreClient as Couvert, dateReservation as Date_, serviceReservation as Service, heure as Heure, idTable as Numero_de_table FROM tblreservation where dateReservation = '".$date."' ORDER BY serviceReservation ASC, heure ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $dateTable);
            $header = false;
            $output_string = "";
            $output_string .=  "<table class='titreRes' id='titreRes' style='border: 10px ridge grey; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 35%; width: 50%; background-color: lightgrey; font-family: Cooper;'>\n";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                if(!$header)
                {
                    $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                    foreach($row as $header => $value)
                    {
                        $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$header}</th>\n";
                    }
                    $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>Supprimer ? </th>";
                    $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
                }
                $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                foreach($row as $value)
                {
                    $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$value}</th>\n";
                }
                $id = $row['Numero_de_reservation'];
                $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'><a href='delete.php?id=";
                $output_string .= $id;
                $output_string .= "'>Supprimer</a></th>";
                $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
            }
            $output_string .= "</table>\n";

            // This echo for jquery 
            echo json_encode($output_string);
        }
   }
   else
   {
        if ($service != "Tout")//Si le service n'est pas null
        {
            if($heure != "Toutes")// Si heure n'est pas null
            {
                $serviceHeureTable = "SELECT idTblReservation as Numero_de_reservation, nombreClient as Couvert, dateReservation as Date_, serviceReservation as Service, heure as Heure, idTable as Numero_de_table FROM tblreservation where serviceReservation = '".$service."' AND heure = '".$heure."' ORDER BY dateReservation ASC";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $serviceHeureTable);
                $header = false;
                $output_string = "";
                $output_string .=  "<table class='titreRes' id='titreRes' style='border: 10px ridge grey; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 35%; width: 50%; background-color: lightgrey; font-family: Cooper;'>\n";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    if(!$header)
                    {
                        $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                        foreach($row as $header => $value)
                        {
                            $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$header}</th>\n";
                        }
                        $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>Supprimer ? </th>";
                        $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
                    }
                    $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                    foreach($row as $value)
                    {
                        $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$value}</th>\n";
                    }
                    $id = $row['Numero_de_reservation'];
                    $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'><a href='delete.php?id=";
                    $output_string .= $id;
                    $output_string .= "'>Supprimer</a></th>";
                    $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
                }
                $output_string .= "</table>\n";

                // This echo for jquery 
                echo json_encode($output_string);
            }
            else if ($heure == "Toutes")
            {
                $serviceTable = "SELECT idTblReservation as Numero_de_reservation, nombreClient as Couvert, dateReservation as Date_, serviceReservation as Service, heure as Heure, idTable as Numero_de_table FROM tblreservation where serviceReservation = '".$service."' ORDER BY dateReservation ASC, heure ASC";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $serviceTable);
                $header = false;
                $output_string = "";
                $output_string .=  "<table class='titreRes' id='titreRes' style='border: 10px ridge grey; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 35%; width: 50%; background-color: lightgrey; font-family: Cooper;'>\n";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    if(!$header)
                    {
                        $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                        foreach($row as $header => $value)
                        {
                            $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$header}</th>\n";
                        }
                        $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>Supprimer ? </th>";
                        $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
                    }
                    $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                    foreach($row as $value)
                    {
                        $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$value}</th>\n";
                    }
                    $id = $row['Numero_de_reservation'];
                    $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'><a href='delete.php?id=";
                    $output_string .= $id;
                    $output_string .= "'>Supprimer</a></th>";
                    $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
                }
                $output_string .= "</table>\n";


                // This echo for jquery 
                echo json_encode($output_string);
            }
        }
        else if ($service == "Tout" && $heure == "Toutes") //Si tout est null
        {
            $touteTable = "SELECT idTblReservation as Numero_de_reservation, nombreClient as Couvert, dateReservation as Date_, serviceReservation as Service, heure as Heure, idTable as Numero_de_table FROM tblreservation";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $touteTable);
            $header = false;
            $output_string = "";
            $output_string .=  "<table class='titreRes' id='titreRes' style='border: 10px ridge grey; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 35%; width: 50%; background-color: lightgrey; font-family: Cooper;'>\n";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                if(!$header)
                {
                    $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                    foreach($row as $header => $value)
                    {
                        $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$header}</th>\n";
                    }
                    $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>Supprimer ? </th>";
                    $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
                }
                $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
                foreach($row as $value)
                {
                    $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'>{$value}</th>\n";
                }
                $id = $row['Numero_de_reservation'];
                $output_string .= "<th style='text-align:center'><a href='delete.php?id=";
                $output_string .= $id;
                $output_string .= "'>Supprimer</a></th>";
                $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
            }
            $output_string .= "</table>\n";

            // This echo for jquery 
            echo json_encode($output_string);
        }
   }

?>
```

The problem doesn't even is in my php code, just the data don't go from my html to my php.
Thank you everyone !

Comment: Please show us ALL the error message, not a summary

Comment: You commented out most of the code. Is that code really commented out when you get the error?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: You are returning a json encode of a simple string. Thats not really JSON, it just encoded as a string. But your js is expecting JSON that could be one of your problems

Comment: @RiggsFolly It was for debug, but here is the error : 
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: service in C:\wamp64\www\Restaurant\PagesDuSite\check-table.php on line 5

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah but i have the nearly same code in an another page and this one works

Comment: The problem is that, for an unknown reason, the data don't go in the check-table.php page

Comment: Odd that it's giving you that message on isset. Try using [array_key_exists](http://php.net/array_key_exists) instead

Comment: @RiggsFolly Blank page

Comment: Sorry my typo - Debug code -  `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST,1) . '</pre>'; exit;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly " Array
(
) "

Comment: Since you're getting an empty object, this may be irrelevant, but don't you need to decode the incoming JSON? likewise, can you just put dataType: json and it properly encode it?

Comment: @ClaytonEngle I don't thin that the problem, in an another page if have exactly the same ajax call, but on an another php page, and there no problem, i will edit my post to show you

Comment: Maybe try $_POST. It's possible your server has unknown settings for $_REQUEST, but we can see from your old script $_POST is working as expected.

Comment: @ClaytonEngle Tried with $_POST, same :(

Answer (score -1):

Since a $_REQUEST var isn't being generated, my best guess is that your two HTML pages are using two different versions of jQuery. If that's the case, you need the new one to use 'method: "POST"', not type:. Either way, look into capturing the xhr data from jQuery's site and log it to the console.

Comment: Nope, you can see in the head of the two html page, they are the same, I tried the change, but it didn't work :(. Can you tell me more about xhr data ?

Comment: Crap I meant to put this as a comment up there. Man. I'm making a lot of mistakes today. Anyways... The only very last thing I can think of... and this is stupid, is wrapping your ternary conditionals in parentheses, like `(isset($_REQUEST['service']) ? $_REQUEST['service'] : 'serviceBug');`, but that likely won't fix the problem. What version of PHP is this?

Comment: jqXHR is the return object for jQuery AJAX. It has a bunch of info in it. If you're using Chrome, you can hit ctrl+shift+i to get to the inspector, and it has a tab for console, where you can run commands and see log outputs. Adding this to your code will give you a log dump: `console.log(whatever you wanna dump);`. the xhr details can be found here in jQuery's documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: PHP version is 7.3.21

Answer (score -1):

When making an Ajax call, which doesn't post if success, just check that the button that calls ajax, isn't in a form tag.